# regExp - How to find my variable only contains the assigned string or not..?

Tags: jquery, regex

I am getting a object value as 3 chance of different string as a) Unassigned b) ( Unassigned ) c) (unassigned)..

my question is how to I find only my variable contains any one of this and without any additional text with that..?

i tried like this, but i am not sure which is correct or not..?

```
var reg = '\bUnassigned\b'

var m = object.name.match(reg)
```

In this i am wondering in case if my name contains more text ("xx Unassigned thins") then i will be in trouble, how can i confirm that only my name contains one word which i need, any one suggest / confirm my approach please..?

Comment: You want to find out if the text is `'unassigned'`, and without any additional characters (parentheses or space)? Given the input what output do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting with parentheses without any addition text info from vaiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be strictly those mentioned before, you can have alternatives with a pipe `|` and by adding `^` to denote start of the string and `$` to denote end of the string, you can match those and nothing else.

```
var reg = new RegExp('^(unassigned|\\( Unassigned \\)|Unassigned)$');
var m = object.name.match(reg);
```

Comment: I am not getting proper result on all 3 approach, se here http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/64v8x/

Comment: Ok. RegExp constructor apparently requires escaped backslashes so that it doesn't escape the next character but keeps the backslash for the final matching. Will fix the regexp. And since the first case did not after all have parenthesis, I removed those as well. Changed Fiddle in here: http://jsfiddle.net/64v8x/1/

Comment: And IF the case is that you need to match `(unassigned)` as well (as I mentioned in the earlier comment, your fiddle did not have the parenthesis), just wrap the first word with `\\(` and `\\)`.